# What's the meaning of ${1:-0} in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I seem at [example 9-14](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html).

```
$ echo ${1:-0}
$ 0
$ echo ${2:-32767}
$ 32767
```

So I cant understand...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> > If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

So, for example, this script:

```
echo "${foo:-1}"
foo=2
echo "${foo:-3}"
foo=
echo "${foo:-4}"
```

prints

```
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is `${var:-$DEFAULT}`. It means if the variable is not set or is `null`, use the default value.